# SQS receive_message does not return any messages

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have the following code for adding a message to SQS queue

```py
response = self.queue.receive_message(
            QueueUrl=self.sqs_endpoint_url,
            AttributeNames=['All'],
            MessageAttributeNames=['All'],
            WaitTimeSeconds=20,
            MaxNumberOfMessages=10
        )
        if response and ('Messages' in response) and (len(response["Messages"]) > 0):
            return response['Messages']
        return None
```

and my single threaded polling process is,

```py
    def poll(self, action):
        config.logger.info('Starting to poll SQS queue...')

        if not action or not callable(action):
            raise ValueError('Callback function `action` not provided for queue polling.')

        while True:
            messages = self.get_messages()
            if messages:
                config.logger.info(f'Processing {len(messages)} messages')
                for message in messages:
                    try:
                        action(message)
                        message_receipt_handle = message["ReceiptHandle"]
                        self.delete_message(message_receipt_handle)
                    except Exception as e:
                        config.logger.error(f'Error in processing a message from queue: {str(e)}')
```

I had queued up 11 messages, however in the logs I observed that only 3 of them were actually read.

```
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Processing 1 messages", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:03:23.933141+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Received message of view_compare", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:03:23.933304+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Updating job(id:1) result", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:03:42.896193+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Deleting message", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:03:44.006373+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Processing 1 messages", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:08:24.812059+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Received message of view_compare", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:08:24.812253+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Updating job(id:2) result", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:08:30.949772+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Deleting message", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:08:32.195995+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Processing 1 messages", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:08:32.897928+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Received message of view_compare", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:08:32.898116+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Updating job(id:11) result", "name": "corpde-tableau", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:08:38.897815+0000"}
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Deleting message", "timestamp": "2020-11-05T19:08:40.094205+0000"}
```

As you can see the `receive_message` even with `MaxNumberOfMessages` set to 10 does not receive all the message, and the rest of the messages (8) are still in flight as per the aws console.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the `ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds` attribute of the queue?

Comment: Is this a FIFO queue or a Standard queue?

Comment: The fact that 8 messages are in-flight suggests that they are either still being processed, or the `delete_message()` operation is not performing correctly.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it's a standard queue.

Comment: @yorodm the `ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds` is set to 20 for long polling

Comment: I suggest you include some logging statements to verify that messages are being correctly deleted. Please note that _any_ access of the messages will put them "in-flight", including just looking at the messages in the SQS console. It is possible that your `action()` is failing and the messages are (correctly) not being deleted. The fact that the messages are "in-flight" means that _something_ has been reading them.